# Can it call a function from outside in eof?

Tags: bash, shell

I tried $(hello) ${hello} in this way, but I did not get any successful results.

```
hello(){
print "Hey I m Here"
 
}
# test
cat -e <<EOF

   
    # hello ?
    hello
EOF
```

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?  What output are you getting?  What bash version is executing this code (assuming it's bash, as stated in the tag)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is bash, command substitution should work: $(hello)

"print", however, will not work.   Change it to "printf" or "echo".

```
bash-3.2$ cat doit.sh
hello(){
printf "Hey I m Here"
 
}
# test
cat -e <<EOF
    # hello ?
    $(hello)
EOF

bash-3.2$ . ./doit.sh
    # hello ?$
    Hey I m Here$
```